# getting invalid product id (in-app purchase)

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, storekit

i'm using this method to validate my products:
- to get the array of products, i first parse a XML file downloaded from a server,
and get a list of products, but the ids are always invalid.

```
- (void) validateProductsIdentifiers:(NSArray *) products {

NSMutableArray *productsIds = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

if (products != nil) {

    for (EJBookInStore * book in products) {
        //for each book, save the book id
        [productsIds addObject:[book idBook]];
    }
    //Verify if the array is not empty
    if ([productsIds count] > 0) {

        SKProductsRequest *productsRequest = [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:[NSSet setWithArray:productsIds]];
        productsRequest.delegate = self;
        [productsRequest start];
    }
} else {

    NSLog(@"Erro...");
}
```

When i put a id directly in the method, the id is validate:

```
   - (void) validateProductsIdentifiers:(NSArray *) products {

    NSMutableArray *productsIds = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    if (products != nil) {

         for (EJBookInStore * book in products) {
            //for each book, save the book id
            [productsIds addObject:[book idBook]];
        }
        //Verify if the array is not empty
        if ([productsIds count] > 0) {
            //When i set the id like this, the id is validated
            NSArray *prodIds = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"com.example.bookA", nil];
            SKProductsRequest *productsRequest = [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:[NSSet setWithArray: prodIds]];
            productsRequest.delegate = self;
            [productsRequest start];
        }
    } else {

        NSLog(@"Error...");
    }
}
```

Comment: If you examine the contents of `productIds` in the debugger before you send it, are the values what you expect? Are the `invalidProductIdentifiers` in the failure response what you expect?

Comment: the object book is sending this output: @"com.example.bookA/n   /n".

Comment: That `/n/n` doesn't look right. Maybe your XML or parser are broken?